# I can't assign a Firestore document's value to a class instance

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a User class instance (currentUser) with 3 parameters: username, email and rating, and a Firestore collection of 'users' with documents including only 3 fields: username, email and rating. I am trying to retrieve the data of the logged user and save it in my currentUser instance and display it using the loadUserData() method, but Android just won't assign the value.

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        ownerProfileRetriever(this.getContext());

        loadUserData(root);

        viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(createCardAdapter());
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
                    }
                }).attach();


        return root;
    }

    private void ownerProfileRetriever(Context context) {
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null ? FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() : null;
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        if (userId == null || userId.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No user id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId);
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

                currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadUserData(View root){
        TextView username = root.findViewById(R.id.username);
        username.setText(currentUser.getUsername());
        TextView email = root.findViewById(R.id.email);
        email.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
        TextView rating = root.findViewById(R.id.ratingValue);
        rating.setText(String.valueOf(currentUser.getRating()));
    }
}
```

When I run it I get no errors, but username, email and rating are not displayed on the screen.
(the date it's not supposed to be displayed in the view pager, just in case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method `loadUserData()` after retrieving the data:

```
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId);
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

                currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                 loadUserData(root);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It really worked! Thanks mate! But, I still don't understand something. I called loadUserData() in onCreateView, just after calling ownerProfileRetriever(), in which I assigned the username,email,rating values to the global currentUser instance. Why did it not work?

Comment: It didnt work because Firebase api is asynchronous this method             `loadUserData(root);` was getting executed before `ownerProfileRetriever(this.getContext());`

Comment: Since the api is asynchronous it means that when running the code it will not wait until the data is retrieved from firestore instead , the code will keep executing and `loadUserData()` got called before retrieving the data from firestore thus nothing was showing on the screen

Comment: Ooook, now I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry mate, me again. I understood the idea, but I am not quiet sure I understand how to control this syncronicity. Now I'm in the same situation using method ownerProfileRetriever() but in a different context. When I try to assign currentUser's username to a maps value, the username seems to not be ready in time again:
[here] (https://imgur.com/DLe35kU).

Comment: The image is not loading with me please add a different question with what code of what you are doing and explanation

Comment: I managed to solve it. It's kinda the same situation. I will just learn more about asynchronous methods, sorry for bothering you and thanks again!